Could we rename [tag:windows-api] to [tag:winapi]?
Could we rename windows-api to winapi? StackOverflow uses the latter, shorter form. It would make sense to go with an established standard here, since this is referring to the same thing anyway.

Good catch. winapi Done.

Thanks @RobertCartaino!
